# Clarity datagrid custom filter issue: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined at FiltersProvider.add (

Tags: filter, datagrid, vmware-clarity, clarity

I am trying to implement a custom filter. my filter code is:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Filter } from "@clr/angular";
import { DatagridFilter } from "@clr/angular";
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";

@Component({
  selector: "app-datagrid-filter"
})
export class AppDatagridFilter {

    changes = new Subject<any>();
    isActive(): boolean {
      return true;
    }
    accepts(item: any): boolean {
      return true;
    }
    filter() {
      console.log('tst');
    }

}
```

In the parent code it's instanstiated as:

```
private datagridFilter = new AppDatagridFilter();
```

In the parent html file i am invoking the custom filter:

```
   <clr-dg-column *ngFor="let column of (gridData$ | async)?.columnDefs">
       {{ column.name }}
       <clr-dg-filter [clrDgFilter]="datagridFilter">
           <app-datagrid-filter #datagridFilter></app-datagrid-filter>
       </clr-dg-filter>
   </clr-dg-column>
```

I am getting this error message from clr-angular.js

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at FiltersProvider.add (clr-angular.js:3388)
    at ClrDatagridFilter.DatagridFilterRegistrar.setFilter (clr-angular.js:3465)
    at ClrDatagridFilter.set [as customFilter] (clr-angular.js:3506)
    at updateProp (core.js:12661)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:12368)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:13935)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:13878)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:14771)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:14712)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (DatagridComponent.html:31)
```

clr-angular.js snippet:

```
FiltersProvider.prototype.add = function (filter) {
    var _this = this;
    var index = this._all.length;
    var subscription = filter.**changes**.subscribe(function () { return _this.resetPageAndEmitFilterChange([filter]); });
```

I am following this example of reusable filter:

https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.11/datagrid/custom-filtering